# Connecting grounds when using an isolated DC/DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, grounding

I am designing a PCB that needs to convert 24V DC to 5V DC @ 8 amps. I would like to use an off-the-shelf converter and virtually everything in that range is an isolated DC-DC converter. Is there any harm in connecting the VOut- to the VIn- and destroying the "isolated" part of the converter (that I do not need in the first place)? I am planning on using a [Murata UEI-30W](http://power.murata.com/data/power/mdc_uei-30w.pdf).

I just want to make sure that there is no downside (i.e. power supply blowing up or unstable) if I connect the input and output grounds. The reason the grounds cannot be isolated is that the devices that requires 5V will share a common metal chassis ground with the devices that require 24V. So, there will be no isolation of grounds regardless.

Comment: Should I isolate grounds of an isolated DC/DC converter? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35800/should-i-isolate-grounds-of-an-isolated-dc-dc-converter?rq=1

Comment: The only downside is that you may be paying more for the isolation (in <currency units> or perhaps in efficiency or some other criteria).

Comment: Thanks - I saw that other question but it was "when should I isolate." In my case I know I don't want to, but I wanted to make sure it was OK to use an isolated PS but not isolate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isolated DC/DC converter *allows* the input and output grounds to be isolated, but does not *require* them to be isolated.

If the input and output grounds must be isolated, Murata should state that very clearly on the datasheet, but I can't visualize any reason for such a requirement.