Multiple DC-DC power supplies and common ground
I am busy designing the power supply end for a system (mostly networking equipment, raspberry pi's etc) that run off a 12v source (effectively an online UPS I built).  Some of the equipment run on 5v, some on 12v and some on 24v.
For 5v and 24v, I have sized appropriate DC-DC power supplies (SD-50A-5 and SD-50A-24 https://www.mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/SD-50.pdf)
For power/environment monitoring side I am using an ESP8266 (using esphome) monitoring a number of INA219s for current and voltage metrics (as well as other sensors) publishing to mqtt.  On a bench test setup this prototype works well with a shared common ground.
However, prior to connecting things together I did a spot check first, expecting (naively, i guess) to find the '- input' and '- output' labelled terminals to be internally connected already, but they are not.  On the 24v supply resistance between them is in the mega ohm range and on the 5v it is in the kilo ohm range.
My question is, can I connect all grounds together as a common ground?  From the online searching I did it would seem like it is ok to, even expected (edit: not for isolated dc-dc supplies!).
And, if so, why would the power supplies not be build with a common ground already?

Those are isolated DC to DC converters, which is why there's no connection between inputs and outputs. It's why the data sheet says "1500VDC I/O isolation". You can connect the outputs however you want, e.g. to make 12-0-12 from a single supply you connect the + output of one to the - output of the other.

Ahh, I recall looking at the datasheet but did not realise what that meant, thanks for the clarification

I have contacted the manufacturer re wiring for a common ground and their answer was basically: no, ideally not

We don’t suggest you do so. Because it will affect the EMI and be non-isolated. You can do so if you don’t care these.


Adding this here in case it helps someone else too (missed it initially) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181088/connecting-grounds-when-using-an-isolated-dc-dc-converter
